# Where exactly are variables stored while vectors store in RAM?

Tags: c++, vector

I used this and compiled it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> articles (119999999,"ads");
    std::cout <<   articles[1];
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Then a memory error occurred that the memory is full (because no loss of information occurred). I opened the task manager and then I opened the program again. The program was consuming 250 megabytes, then my computer suddenly shutdown. I asked myself why when I declare many variables and arrays, there is no memory error.

So much so that I wrote a program to create a text file and then write thousands of variables and then I translated that file and the program opened normally!

Where are variables stored? And are vectors stored in RAM only?

Comment: What computer / OS are you using? I'm not sure about the 250 MB but on my PC this wouldn't cause an out-of-memory shutdown...

Comment: _And are vectors stored in RAM only?_ Of course, they are. Where else should they be stored?

Comment: I am using HP. 2 GB of ram.

Comment: On my system it consumes a more reasonable 3.5 MB.

Comment: The program compiled for x86 or x64?

Comment: Usually everything in your program will be stored in the RAM. It is OS-depending what happens when your RAM is full. Linux usually uses a swap partition on your hard drive to get some extra RAM, but that will slow down everything dramatically.

Comment: If you compile with debug options there might be some extra memory foot print for loaded libraries and the corresponding debug info. But I still struggle to believe that all will sum up to 250 GB...

Comment: _I am using HP._ A PC? With Windows or Linux? Which compiler? Which platform? With which options compiled?

Comment: sorry guys it was this 119999999 . I will edit my question

Comment: I am using mingw. windows.

Comment: 119999999 * 32 = 3'839'999'968. That means over 3 GB. Please, care of the numbers...

Comment: With memory limitation in mind, you should start with a vector of minimal size and rely on that it will re-allocate when necessary. (That's the actual reason to use a `std::vector`.) That will ensure that your application is usable as long as the data fits into memory (instead of a pessimistic allocation from the beginning which even doesn't work on your PC).

Comment: but what about variables I tried the same way of vectors but the program opened normally.

Comment: Phew. I'm glad it was a typo in the question. I thought my world was falling in. (Although the program runs on my very powerful desktop computer ;-) )

Comment: "I tried the same way of vectors" -- that's not very helpful as a description, provide code instead. Also, just wondering, what is `sizeof (std::string)` and `sizeof (void*)` on your machine?

Comment: on my machine. the size of string is 32 and 8 in void*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(std::string)` is typically 32 bytes. Even with short string optimisation, the memory request is a contiguous block of 119999999 * 32 bytes. That's of the order of 4Gb and beyond the capability of your computer.

If you require the storage of duplicate strings then consider `std::reference_wrapper` as the vector element type.